# Prestashop links to the wrong category

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I recently created new category of products.
The ID and name are base of every link in my shop like in example below.

```
www.example.com/ID-CATEGORY_NAME
```

Newest category with ID 12 somehow links to one of the old categories.
So instead of redirecting to `www.example.com/12-categorynew` it links to `www.example.com/5-categoryold` which is valid link but for another category of products. Any idea what may caused that? I'm running 1.7.5.2 version. No change in code was made yet.

Answer (score 0):

You probably already found a solution; however, I would start with the following:

1. Try to clear the cache.
2. Try regenerating the category tree.

The reason I answer is different though: If you have not updated your Prestashop yet, then do so quickly. For versions < 1.7.8.7, a security issue was found back in July of 2022. You should have been notified by Prestashop about this.